# ant command to start a new terminal and execute command on mac

Tags: mac, terminal, java, node.js, ant

I am trying to open a new terminal window in mac and execute a node command via ant

```
   <exec osfamily="unix" dir="${dir}" executable="open" failonerror="true">
            <env key="MONGODB_HOST" value="${mongo.host}"/>
            <env key="MONGODB_DATABASE" value="${mongo.dbname}"/>
            <arg line="-a Terminal ."/>
        </exec>
   <exec osfamily="unix" dir="${dir}" executable="node" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="${app.file.name}.js "/>
        </exec>
```

However the second exec executes within the old terminal window and not the new one that is opened by the first exec

Can anyone please guide me as to how I can execute the second exec within the context of the new terminal window

I am trying to emulate the basic functionality of

- opening a new terminal window
- setting environment variables
- and executing node server.js

via the ant command on a mac

Answer (score 0):

i was finally able to do it using the following shell scripts and calling them from ant :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589114/opening-a-new-terminal-tab-in-osxsnow-leopard-with-the-opening-terminal-window

```
#!/bin/sh
pwd=`pwd`
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd $pwd; clear\"" > /dev/null
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh

pwd=`pwd`
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\"" \
    -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"t\" using {command down}" \
    -e "do script \"cd $pwd; clear\" in front window" \
    -e "end tell"
    > /dev/null
```